# MongoDb Remote Server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, node.js, terminal

I got a work of node.js and mongodb. While running node.js it gives error of permission denied.

For going alternatively when I tried to connect to remote server

You are trying to access MongoDB on the native driver port. For http diagnostic access, add 1000 to the port number...

I just want to reach to the REMOTE DB of client so that I can configure it on local end and experiment things.....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that you have tried to use a web browser to connect to the MongoDB native port, eg:

```
http://localhost:27017
```

If you want to use the [MongoDB interactive shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongo+-+The+Interactive+Shell) to try database commands, you need to use the command line `mongo`:

```
$ mongo

MongoDB shell version: 2.0.6
connecting to: test
>
```

`mongo` will connect to localhost:27017 by default.  You can also specify a host and port, eg:

```
mongo localhost:27017
```

The mention of connecting by adding 1000 to the port number is referring to the MongoDB [simple REST interface](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface#HttpInterface-SimpleRESTInterface) which is a read-only administrative interface accessible via a web browser:

```
http://localhost:28017/
```